# Compile one permutation per time?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Is there any way to set `gwt compiler` so that each permutation is compiled until finish before proceeding with next permutation?

Currently, I am already running out of heap memory even though `Xmx` already set to 2gb on 64bits system. I don't mind it being slow as long as it able to finish compiling all the permutations

Comment: try to increase Xmx beyond 2gb. My project also is not so big, it requires 1gb to compile.

Comment: For some compilers (not sure if that includes GWT), going beyond 2gb actually makes it worse on some OS's. When you give more memory to a process, you're actually giving less memory to the swap space. Really wierd and counter-intuitive. Usually 2GB is the sweat spot on computers from 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `localWorkers` to `1` (or maybe even better: your number of cores minus 1).

We're using maven and in the *default* profile we build a `FastCompiledGuvnor` module and in the *full* profile we do the real `Guvnor` module:

```
  <plugin>
    <!--use -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true to skip GWT compiler-->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-1</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- The default profile needs to be fast, so we only build 1 permutation { -->
      <module>org.drools.guvnor.FastCompiledGuvnor</module>
      <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
      <!-- } -->
      <runTarget>org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/Guvnor.html</runTarget>
      <compileSourcesArtifacts>
        <compileSourcesArtifact>org.drools:drools-factconstraint</compileSourcesArtifact>
        <compileSourcesArtifact>org.drools:drools-ide-common</compileSourcesArtifact>
      </compileSourcesArtifacts>
      <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath><!-- The GWT compiler must the correct JDT version -->
      <localWorkers>2</localWorkers><!-- Using all workers can temporarily hang the mouse and isn't much faster -->
      <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512m</extraJvmArgs>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>

    ... profile ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Build all GWT permutations and optimize them -->
          <module>org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor</module>
          <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: how big is your project? do u think something wrong as i required so big xmx ? i still getting out of heap size even with localworker 1. ya it's for production, so i required to compile all the permutations

Comment: It's big. Doing all 36 (6*6) permutations takes over a minute to build and we might include more languages in the future.